# Hi, i am using a unity dedicated server services with netcode, i have backfilling enabled in the project

Tags: unity-game-engine, server

. there is a player prefab that is spawned by networkManager when a connection is establised, i want to send a serverRpc from client to server to enble and disable some objects in playerprefab is synced among other clients, the main issue i am having is that my serverRpc is not working, i know that serverRpcs dont work on Server but if you send thw Rpc through client it should work but mine dosent work, help!

```
    public override void OnNetworkSpawn()
    {
        base.OnNetworkSpawn();
        if (PlayerHandler.instance.MultiPlayer)
        {
            print(1);
            print(ModelNo.Value);
            if (IsClient && IsOwner)
            {
                ModelNo = new NetworkVariable<int>(
            PlayerHandler.instance.ModelNo,
            NetworkVariableReadPermission.Everyone,
            NetworkVariableWritePermission.Owner
            );
                ActivateModelServerRpc();
            }
            
        }

    }
    [ClientRpc]
    void ActivateModelClientRpc()
    {
        print(2);

        for (int i = 0; i < models.Count; i++)
        {
            if (i == ModelNo.Value)
            {
                models[i].SetActive(true);
            }
            else
            {
                models[i].SetActive(false);
            }
        }
        
    }
    [ServerRpc (RequireOwnership = false)]
    void ActivateModelServerRpc()
    {
        ActivateModelClientRpc();
    }
```

Comment: could you use a more descriptive title please?